# Cython / C++ any repos of good example?

Tags: c++, cython

Tried googling this morning - and found this

https://gist.github.com/cournape/1077528

But I ran python3 setup.py install - and that's not what I really wanted.  I would like to wrap my c++ in python and not install locally.

So I see

```
├── build
│   ├── lib.linux-x86_64-3.4
│   │   ├── rectangle.cpython-34m.so
│   │   └── rect.cpython-34m.so
│   └── temp.linux-x86_64-3.4
│       ├── rectangle.o
│       ├── Rectangle.o
│       └── rect.o
├── rectangle.c
├── rectangle.cpp
├── Rectangle.cpp
├── Rectangle.h
├── rectangle.pyx
├── rect.cpp
├── rect.pyx
└── setup.py
```

Now I can use the module because it's installed - but how would I use it if it was compiled in place?